# Can we run Azure speech containers on Openshift?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, speech

can we run Microsoft speech containers on Openshift? What should we take into account when trying this?

Br, Ville

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. OpenShift can run any Docker container, so running Azure Cognitive Services containers works just fine

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-container-howto?tabs=stt%2Ccsharp%2Csimple-format

Answer (score 1):

Carlos is correct. However, I should mention that OpenShift adds some security requirements for the containers running on the platform. Some of those concerns have not been properly addressed until 2.2.0 release of speech containers.

Thus, I recommend you start with the latest containers, and definitely raise issues if you hit any.